# How to do multiple while query from 2 different tables in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I do multiple while query from 2 different table?

My code looks like this now:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_group WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$group = $row['group'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM matches WHERE group_name1 = '$group' OR group_name2 = '$group'";
$result = $connection->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
//some HTML code
}
  }
?>
```

It's works but showing only one row from the matches table because of the first query (?) where I get the '$row['group'];'

Comment: Step 1:  use prepared statements. Step 2: use different variable names for each `$result`

Comment: step 3: you don't need 2 queries, one query with a join would be more efficient

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Use `WHERE x IN (a, b)` rather than `WHERE x=a OR x=b`.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code. You're using both styles here inconsistently for no apparent reason.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Then how can I add $_GET to the query safely? can you give me an example please?

Comment: @gezuka Follow the links in tadman's comment, there are examples there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all the results from the first query, and then perform the second query within the loop.

But it's better to join the two queries into one.

```
$query = "
    SELECT m.col1, m.col2, m.col3, ...
    FROM matches AS m
    JOIN user_group AS g ON g.group IN (m.group_name1, m.group_name2)
    WHERE g.email = ?";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3, ...);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // some code that uses the variables $col1, $col2, $col3, ...
}
```

Replace `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, etc. with the actual column names from your table.